# Alamofire string parameter hardcoded works but passing as string parameter does not

Tags: json, swift, string, alamofire

I'm attempting to make a Alamofire service call to retrieve a list of items in JSON. The issue I am having is that anytime I type in a special character: such as ' it somewhere resolves the string a unicode string while sending the request. When I type in o'sheas its coming back that I'm searching O\U2019sheas

```
func sendGetRequest(passedInString: String) {

    PARAMETERS["searchTxt"] = passedInString

    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get , parameters: PARAMETERS, headers: HEADER)

            .validate(statusCode: 200..<400)

            .responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response.request!)
                switch response.result {
                      // GETTING NO RESULTS BECAUSE THE REQUEST IS TURNING the o'sheas into O\U2019sheas
```

But the odd thing is, if I just replace this:

```
 PARAMETERS["searchTxt"] = passedInString
```

with a hardcoded string (the one I'm typing initially and getting no results)

```
 PARAMETERS["searchTxt"] = "o'sheas"
```

...it works just fine and does not convert this to O\U2019sheas. Any idea how to fix this, and more importantly, why this is happening when passed in as a String parameter as opposed to hard coded string?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried adding the URLEncoding.default as the encoding parameter, same results.

I've also tried creating a Swift String Extension to be used on the searchTxt as passing it as parameter like so:

```
PARAMETERS["searchTxt"] = passedInString.escapeSpecialCharacters()








extension String {
    mutating func escapeSpecialCharacters() {
        // 1. Define replacements
        let replacementCharacters = ["'" : "\'"]
        // 2. Cycle through each replacement defined in the replacementCharacters array and remodify the string accordingly.
        replacementCharacters.keys.forEach {
            // 3. Replacing self with new modified string
            self = self.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: replacementCharacters[$0]!)
        }
    }
}
```

But same results.

Comment: It is not quite clear what your `passedInString` is and why it is that way. It may be a bad name, but usually Swift is good at encoding special characters in a sensible (Unicode) way. What you showed looks like a double escape problem on your input parameter. Where does it come from? Could you try to call your function (which has a bad name as well) with _exactly_ the same String as you passed when you hardcoded it?

Comment: Have you tried calling the URL directly from your browser, with the parameter?  Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are sure about this Unicode problem, then you can use Encoder and Decoder functionality to handle this.
2. Or if you know the your String always will be same, then use Regex expression to append '\'

Comment: I logged the response.request and it's coming back as this:

O\U2019shaes for the searchTxt, which is why it's not returning results.

When I hardcoded "O'sheas" as mention above instead of relying on what's typed, it returns the results and the response request for searchTxt is as expected: "O'sheas"

Comment: I also tried writing a swift extension to escape any characters, will update post above.

Comment: I would like to understand more, actually you should encode before passing that parameter into function. For Ex: User input O'sheas in text field and encode it then pass that parameter into the required function. Once you received that value again decode to get actual value. Are you doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the "get" - cause it will use your string in the URL as parameter, the "'" can't be handelt so well.

Try to create a url with URLComponents

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = scheme
urlComponents.host = host
urlComponents.path = path
urlComponents.queryItems = [queryItem]
```

then use urlComponents.url in

`Alamofire.request(urlComponents.url, method: .get, headers: HEADERS)` {...}

```
URLQueryItem(name: "Param", value: "eter")
```

Comment: Unfortunately still the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines of code. May help you.

```
originalString = "o'sheas"
var escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
PARAMETERS["searchTxt"] = escapedString
```